# How to redirect when clicking outside bootstrap modal-content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a modal in my webpage where i've already made it so that when close button is clicked it redirects to the homepage. But i also need it to redirect to the homepage when clicking outside the bootstrap modal, i.e the `".modal-content"` class . 
I tried to do this

```
$('#enterCodeModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    window.location.replace='index.html';
});
```

by looking at other post similar to this but it did'nt work. It would be a great help if someone could help me solve this.

Comment: try window.location.href = '...';

Comment: yes i've already tried that as well

Comment: Does your event fire or is just the redirect not working?

Comment: `window.location.href = '';` should work

Comment: it doesnt do anything , nothing happens

Comment: Any errors? Are you sure the modal's id is `enterCodeModal`?

Comment: yeah i've done similar thing to this by redirecting the page when the close button is clicked

Comment: does having  data-backdrop="static" change anything

Comment: Please see my working answer, and try to see what you did wrong using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works with `window.location.href` as you can see here :

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
    window.location.href = 'https://google.com'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it seemed the problem was data-backdrop="static" thanks for the answer